# How can I change a specific constraints on the last UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, constraints

I need to change the last UITAbleViewCell Bottom Constraints constant on runtime.

I've added an identifier on IB, and I've added the following extension to my UIView.

```
func getConstraintById(id:String) -> NSLayoutConstraint?{
        let constraints = self.constraints()
        for c in constraints{
            if((c as! NSLayoutConstraint).identifier == id){
              return c as? NSLayoutConstraint
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

All works fine, but it seems redundant to iterate all constraints for each cell.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding a custom `UITableView` class with an outlet to the needed constraint, then I had a direct approach on my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomPadding: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Method:

```
if(index + 1 == ITEMS?.count){
    cell.bottomPadding.constant = 5
}else{
     cell.bottomPadding.constant = 0
}
```